# What does an LHC Beam Dump sound like?

Tags: large-hadron-collider, particle-accelerators

What does an LHC Beam Dump sound like?

Is it under a vacuum so that it doesn't make a sound, or does it go boom? Surely the heat generated instantly would make some kind of noise.

This article https://www.lhc-closer.es/taking_a_closer_look_at_lhc/0.lhc_layout says the dump is located at the end of a 700m vacuum line.

There's a video here of the graphite core being upgraded: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjLS9MZ0Ohs. It's "air cooled" so it must not be under vacuum.

There must be a recording of the particle beam hitting that core. Where could I find and hear it? You know, for science!

Comment: Related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider#Operational_challenges

Comment: https://home.cern/news/news/accelerators/autopsy-lhc-beam-dump

Comment: "It's "air cooled" so it must not be under vacuum."  this cannot be correct.You are seeing the installation. It is impossible that the beams being dumbed go through air! There must be a vacuum up to the dump, the energy can not  dissipate in air!.

Comment: not what you ask, but this might interest you https://newatlas.com/quantizer/43568/

Answer (score 3):

The closest I could find is a recording of the beam hitting the carbon jaws of the collimator. You can hear this on the [LHC collimator project web site](http://lhc-collimation-project.web.cern.ch/sounds_and_movies.php).

This was at less than a tenth of the full beam energy, but it still made a clearly audible sound. I would guess what we are hearing is the ringing of the steel casing around the equipment. Given that the dumps are graphite cylinders inside a steel casing I would guess the sound from the dumps would be broadly similar.

The site does not say how the sound was produced, but the rapid changes in temperature and associated thermal expansion probably produced shock waves in the graphite that set the casing oscillating when they reached it. I note that cracks in the graphite were found when the dumps were cut open for inspection, so they have clearly been subjected to mechanical stresses.